# Jquery plugin make it bind onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have a jquery plugin which i have purchased from code canyon for social sharing.

I have it configured for single item sharing, however I wish to make it connected to multiple instances on a page.

```
<script>
$('a.shareplus').shareplus({
    icons: "facebook,twitter,google",
    height : '150px',
    width : '150px',
    shareurl : '#application.settings.websiteurl#/article/' + $(this).attr('data-href'),
    displayTitle : true,
    title : 'Share this item from',
    sticker : false,
    pin : false,
    gplus : false,
    tweets : false,
    fbLikebox : false
});
</script>
```

This works perfectly for a single item that is shared on a webpage. Ive searched the documentation for this plugin, however I cant find any reference for it to be attached to multiple items on a single page.

What Im wondering is.. Im thinking about using the .bind() method to connect to it on click and using the data-href custom attribute to define the page for it to be connected to.

But this doesnt seem to work.

```
<script>
$('a.shareplus').bind('click',shareplus({
    icons: "facebook,twitter,google",
    height : '150px',
    width : '150px',
    shareurl : '#application.settings.websiteurl#/article/' + $(this).attr('data-href'),
    displayTitle : true,
    title : 'Share this item from',
    sticker : false,
    pin : false,
    gplus : false,
    tweets : false,
    fbLikebox : false
});


})</script>
```

Im not too sure on how to connect the bind api to links that contain functions that have parameters so any help greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? `bind` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your code in [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) and use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind) also use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) for `data attributes` like,

```
$(function(){
    $('a.shareplus').on('click',function(){
        $(this).shareplus({
            icons: "facebook,twitter,google",
            height : '150px',
            width : '150px',
            shareurl : '#application.settings.websiteurl#/article/'+$(this).data('href'),
            displayTitle : true,
            title : 'Share this item from',
            sticker : false,
            pin : false,
            gplus : false,
            tweets : false,
            fbLikebox : false
        });
    });
});
```